# Trying Using OAuth2 causes a NOT authorized client or scope error

Tags: vb.net, authorization

I need to be authorized to use Calendar API thru a Service Account.

As soon as I issue the -Dim ok As Boolean = Await GetToken- instruction I get an error and I can't go on. Pls can someone help me? TIA

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Error details:
  Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponseException non è stata gestita
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Unauthorized client or scope in request.", Uri:""
  Source=Microsoft.Threading.Tasks
  StackTrace:
       in Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       in Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
       in Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.d__b.MoveNext() in c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\test\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\ServiceAccountCredential.cs:riga 282
    --- Fine traccia dello stack da posizione precedente dove è stata generata l'eccezione ---
       in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       in UGO_Cont.GoogleCalendarMgt.VB$StateMachine_0_GetAccessToken.MoveNext() in D:\inetpub\wwwroot\UGO_Cont.Web\Services\GoogleCalendarMgt.svc.vb:riga 160
    --- Fine traccia dello stack da posizione precedente dove è stata generata l'eccezione ---
       in System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__5(Object state)
       in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       in System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       in System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
  InnerException: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Here's the Code I use:

```
Private Const SVCACCMAIL = "999999999999-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
Private Const ACTIVITY_ID = "x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9x9"

<OperationContract()>
Public Function InsertEvent(authToken As String, id_Azienda As Integer, id_Azione As Integer, id_Op As Integer) As String
    Dim scopes As New List(Of String)
    scopes.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar")
    Dim inzlzr As New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(SVCACCMAIL) With {.User = SVCACCMAIL, .Scopes = scopes}
    Dim credential As New ServiceAccountCredential(inzlzr.FromCertificate(GetCert))

    GetAccessToken(credential)
End Function

Public Function GetCert() As X509Certificate2
    Dim fileCert As String = "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\UGO_Cont.Web\UGO-Adv-CRM-999999999999999a.p12"
    Dim cert = New X509Certificate2(fileCert, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)
    Return cert
End Function

Async Sub GetAccessToken(cr As ServiceAccountCredential)
    Dim GetToken = cr.RequestAccessTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None)

    Dim ok As Boolean = Await GetToken
    Dim service As New CalendarService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {.ApplicationName = "Test calendar sync app", .HttpClientInitializer = cr})

    Dim list As IList(Of CalendarListEntry) = service.CalendarList.List().Execute().Items()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Watching at some working samples, I've seen that ServiceAccounCtredential's initializer don't have ".User" parameter. Thus, striping out this parameter, I've no more authentication error. So I think the authentication error has gone. These are the working lines:

```
    Dim inzlzr As New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(SVCACCMAIL) With {.Scopes = scopes}
```

Thanks anyway for each one who watched this issue.

(Now I'm starting to try making a working calendars' events insertion to sync our internal CRM)

S.Tedeschi